# Set text size to the same size at the recent call contact name

Tags: swift, uitableview, dynamic, fonts, cell

I am trying to set my font to the same dynamic size as ios' recent call name row. Below is the code that I am using but I am unsure what text style I should be using.

```
cell.nameLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.headline)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about following?

```
cell.nameLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
cell.nameLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.7;
cell.nameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
```

**Update**:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  [self configureView];
}

- (void)didChangePreferredContentSize:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  [self configureView];
}

- (void)configureView
{
  self.textSizeLabel.text = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] preferredContentSizeCategory];
  self.headlineLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];
}
```

Comment: I need the textstyle since I have to match that exact size but thank you.

Comment: so you are sure that headline is the textstyle for the contact name in ios?